# How to insert objectId into an array in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of students in my jqgrid. If I want to assign a list of students to an employee, then I just check the students I want and then I assign to an employee such that the employee record looks like below

My employee record:

```
 {
      "_id": "ObjectId("58622e3bf39d570b21ece1b3")",
      "name" : "Alex",
      "__v" : 6.0,
        "students" : [ 
          "586f8f0cd26a47718b9db4d6", 
          "586f8ef5d26a47718b9db4d4", 
          "586538693b5b5d5d8bc46b1f"
        ]
    }
```

My model for student field:

```
  students: {
    type: Array,
    default: ''
  },
```

My backend code:

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  var body = req.body;
  employee = _.extend(employee, req.body);
  employee.save(function (err) {})
};
```

Here I am ok up to this but I failed to do 2 things here

1. I want to store student id as

   ```
   ObjectId("58622e3bf39d570b21ece1b3")
   ```

   but it is stored as

   ```
   58622e3bf39d570b21ece1b3
   ```
2. When I assign students it should not insert the duplicate record i.e the student already exists should not be inserted again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions there and several problems.

1. Your `students` array.

You should specify the type of items in the array, then mongoose will convert those to items to ObjectID, even though they come as string from frontend. So your schema should look more like this:

```
students: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }]
```

2. Ensuring uniqueness

MongoDB can ensure uniquess only accross entire collection, not a single array. But you can do that by using $addToSet -> mongoDB will then make sure to skip dupes.

*Edit: as per comment request, showing an example on subarray uniqueness.*

As I've said, you cannot have MongoDB put an index on items in a single document. You have to do that in the app. But as I've also said, you can just use $addToSet directly. E.g.

```
employees.update({
    _id: req.params.id
  },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      students: {
        $each: req.body.studetns
      }
    }
  }).exec().then(response => res.json(response)).catch(next); // or whatever.
```

Comment: Thanks Zlatko, i cleared my first problem  but i have to see your solution for my 2nd problem.

Comment: Oh, that's a bit elaborate, but lemme try.

Comment: I am not sure but if you can paste some code i can check in my machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132691/discussion-between-nlr-p-and-zlatko).